# Notepad++ isn't running code

Tags: notepad++

When I hit F5 and try to run a saved piece of code (Python) the console only flashes on the screen (blank) for less than half a second. Has anyone else had this problem? Is there a solution?

Comment: Is your code working? It probably is giving you some error and closing the console.

Comment: Start a console (or terminal) and run your code inside it

Comment: I've tried it in an online code editor and it worked properly, and it isn't running anything, even simple print statements

Answer (score -1):

If you issues with debuggers that are not working, activate debugging with code. It is not elegant but often the most effective solution. [Here is how it works for python](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/debugging-in-python/).

Breakpoints are mentioned as well. I hope this helps for you.